# irreducible components of exceptional divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a non-singular projective variety defined over the complex numbers, and let $Y\subset X$ be a non-singular subvariety.  Denote by $\phi: \tilde{X} \dashrightarrow X$ the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$.  We know that the exceptional divisor $E := \phi^{-1}(Y)$ need not be irreducible.

Question:  What can we say about the *intersection* of the irreducible components of $E$?  e.g.~are they pairwise disjoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $Y$ disconnected the only way you can have a non-irreducible exceptional divisor when $X$ and $Y$ are smooth? (Sufficiently locally, the blowup of $X$ along $Y$ looks like the blowup of $\Bbb A^n$ in $\Bbb A^m$ for some $m<n$.) In this case, all the irreducible components are disjoint.

Comment: @KReiser:  Take $X$ to be the nodal cubic, and $Y$ the unique singular point.  Then the exceptional divisor consists of two distinct points.

Comment: From your post: "Let $X$ be a non-singular projective variety...". The nodal cubic is singular.

Comment: @KReiser:  Good point!  Could you please give me an alternative (algebraic) justification of your initial claim, and make it a reply?  That would qualify for an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The exceptional divisor is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_{Y}(N)$ where $N$ is the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$ (a projective space bundle over $Y$). Hence, it is connected.